# Error: Embedded binary is not signed with the same certificate as the parent app

Tags: xcode, code-signing

I am using OpenVPNAdapter library in my project for months. But suddenly, I don't know why, it started to give this error while I am trying to package. I tried to change SHA1 code in the occurences of the project via Sublime Text, but it didn't work. Do you have any idea to help me please?

```
    Embedded binary is not signed with the same certificate as the parent app. Verify the embedded binary target's code sign settings match the parent app's

    Embedded Binary Signing Certificate:    iPhone Developer: Salih Balkan (5P7FM4G8DY)
    (SHA1 Hash: 4F9B1A9F1BD61A0448B55B0D99224C63217FA4FA)

    Parent App Signing Certificate:     iPhone Developer: Salih Balkan (5P7FM4G8DY)
    (SHA1 Hash: 575CC2961C25C553C66CE41A5D409D08BFC0EA17)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally resolved it! It was because of using .appex file embedded in my project files, instead of compiling while packaging. I wasn't able to rebuild .appex in my forked project, beacuse I directly copied the .appex file from Products folder of the forked app months ago. I fixed the problem by setting bundle identifier and rebuilding the project (so the .appex file too) from the forked project and pasting the new .appex file to my project.